# Postgres: How to convert some flag-like/binary number to its binary representation and back?

Tags: postgresql

E.g. `195` decimal which should be shown as `11000011` binary (mantissa 2) and vice versa, since it represents encoded flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 195::bit(8)::text,  '11000011'::bit(8)::int
 text     int4
 -------- ----
 11000011  195
```

cool and easy :)